# Details of projects done by R Diwakar

Tags: crew

I noticed the name R Diwakar in the opening credits of one of the best movies I have seen, Mumbai Police (Malayalam) as its cinematographer. Taken aback by the superb visuals and camera movements in the movie, I tried digging up some more information on past projects Diwakar has been associated with. But I could not find a Wikipedia or IMDB entry or any other links that was enough to give an idea about his works.

Could some one help sharing his professional history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd preface this by saying that I'm no expert in this type of cinema. But there's a [cinematographer on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1492541/) who goes by **R. Diwakaran\Divakaran** and one of the 3 films listed in his profile is [Notebook](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0924260/combined) by *Mumbai Police* director Rosshan Andrrews. So it might be the same guy. Note also that Mumbai Police's [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumbai_Police_%28film%29) inexplicably called the cinematographer both **R. Diwakar** and **G. Diwakaran**.

Googling R. Diwakaran\Divakaran reveals more movies he shot, like the Malayalam movie [Evidam Swargamanu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidam_Swargamanu) from 2009, and [How Old Are You](http://www.movieslantern.com/movies/profile.php?Filmid=716) (*also* directed by Andrrews) which came out a couple of weeks ago.

IMDb also lists a cinematographer simply called [Diwakar](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1194339/) but he shot Telugu films, so it might not be him.

Comment: Also, R Divakar appears to be a synonym for R Diwakar, and Divakar has 5 other movies to his credit.

Comment: On IMDb? I can't find him. I only found a cinematographer called Diwakar (sans R), but wasn't sure it was the same guy so didn't include him: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1194339/

Comment: That's who I was thinking of. He came up several times in my google-fu mashups.

Comment: A torrent site (though not the most reliable of sources) calls him 'P Diwakar' in one of those movies. So this might be a different guy.

Comment: @Walt torrent site mostly are wrong with this information.

Comment: I know. But also, the films he shot are in Telugu, not Tamil\Malayalam.